# Create div tag template and reuse

Tags: jquery

Is it possible to create a template e.g  with lots of other elements inside it with proper attribute "tagging" and reuse it with jquery? For instance when you want to display user submitted comments without refreshing the page. The reason I ask this is because the code  between the div tags are rather long. So using for instance prepend() would be to long to rewrite.

Whats the best approach for larger manipulations? Create a separate html? Im pretty new to manipulation, but since I have a programming background i would expect that there is an efficient way to reuse already existing HTML instead of redefining it in jquery.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create  a  div tag with all the elements inside it..

If you want to reuse it you can use the `.clone()` to a template similar to div and append it to your html..

```
<div class="template">
   // All other elements here
</div>

<div id="container">
</div>


$template = $('.template').clone() ; //  Clones the template div

// Append to your contianer

$('#container').append($template) ;
```

Comment: What if I want to change some of the attributes? $template.$('selector').attr('id', jsonarray.value); ?

Comment: That will only affect the cloned object.. If you to change the whole template as well you can do that as well